# URL Scheme for sharing on Google+, VK and Reddit (iOS)

Tags: ios, google-plus, url-scheme, reddit, vk

I would like to share a content from my app without the use of any third party libraries. For that I am tring to use URL Scheme, but haveing trubble of finding the proper URL Scheme for sharing on **Google+**, **VK** and **Reddit**. Here is what I am doing to whatsapp:

```
let url = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=hello")

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) 
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
else 
{
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Hello!  Did you find a solution? Or what did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use share kit instead .You can find it right [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)

Comment: I am writing a third party SDK and do not want to be dependent on other third parties. So I using only native iOS stuff.

Comment: then look at what the library does.